# Exchange Web Services causes transaction logs growth

Tags: exchange-2007, web-services, edb

I'm using EWS on an Exchange 2007 with basic authentication. I'm calling just the FindItems() method and the transaction log seem to grow alarmingly.

On my test server I ran an endless loop calling FindItems() and the logs grew with 1 MB per 5-6 minutes. In an production environment, calling this would cause a growth of 1 MB per 10-15 seconds!

Why does the transaction log grow when I only make read-only requests to the EWS?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I've run into the same thing, and I'm pretty much stuck trying to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the production server makes more logs. It is possible your test-server didn't log these events while the production server does. This is a setting. More info:
http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/managing-exchange-server-2007-log-files-part2.html

Comment: IIS logs != Exchange Transaction Logs

Comment: @Ben: you are right. In all 3 parts of the blog mentioned by @TiZon I couldn't find out if there is a possibility to see the contents of the transaction logs. I want a way to find out what "transactions" are logged, if I only make read-only requests through the EWS.